# How to always include schema when email is sent?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-schemas

We have a shared email account on our domain, that is accessed by several employees. How can I include the Schema for a review system (very similar to the [Review Action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/review-action) in Google's example) whenever an email is sent through this domain?

The idea is when we liaise with externals to the immediate team (still on the same domain); there will be a email thread going back and forth and at the end; I want them to be able to leave a mini review of how happy they are with our service. I can then write this feedback to a Google Spreadsheet.

I can get the example working and everything works well in the development environment but following the tutorial and doing a bit of background reading - I can only include it in emails that I send through Google App script. How can I include the script in every email sent through that shared account?

Comment: Its against google tos to share email accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to your Google Account via SMTP and send emails with markup through it, so that your DKIM/SPF configuration is respected.

I wrote a simple tool in Python that does exactly that, and that includes templates for the common action types, including the ReviewAction:

https://github.com/claudiocherubino/gmailer